# Port forwarding on D-Link DIR-615 super-slow, useless

Tags: router, performance, port-forwarding

I have replaced my old router with DIR-615 from D-Link, and now the port forwarding is so slow it makes the router practically useless for requests coming from outside of my network.

Accessing the router itself (admin UI) from outside is without any issues, no delay whatsoever. But when I try to access a service residing on any of the computers in my network from outside the requests take minutes and minutes. E.g. I can see source of my GWT-app main page, but loading additional CSS and JS files takes years.

If anyone could recommend any further diagnostics I should do to figure out what is happening it would be great.

Few notes:

- happens with more services (web-app on Tomcat, viewing directory index via Apache)
- it does not make a difference whether the service is hosted on wired or wireless PC
- accessing the service on a localhost works fine, as does any 'inner' communication
- turning off firewall on target PC does not make difference either (makes sense)
- when I replace this router with the old one (both 192.168.1.1) everything works fine
- I see nothing suspicious in the router's log
- I believe I have the latest firmware (4.11)
- DIR-615 sucks, it already died once completely

**Update:**

1. After re-running the loading tests with buddy of mine (who resides in another city), it appears that the issue is only **limited to access from my network using public IP**. (Now the guy reports <5s, formerly it was 15-20-ish. But I assume now it was caused by some kind of temporary traffic spikes.)
2. **Latency** of the linked resources is what kills the loading process, their download itself is fine. The tool shows 42s latency for 2kB CSS-file, while the d/l is 9ms. But given the above mentioned I should probably close this issue and maybe open a new one, with the issue re-formulated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future reference, I think [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/37421/accessing-a-website-via-the-webservers-public-ip-from-a-pc-within-the-same-lan) describes the issue. It is a network issue after-all. And given DIR-615 does not support NAT loopback I will have to 'solve' this using hosts, which is dirty but will have to do...