# Static ip can't be browsed locally - Windows server 2012

Tags: networking, router, dns, ip, windows-server-2012

We have a machine with Windows server 2012. We used to host the websites through a static ip. The strange problem is we are not able to locally browse the hosted sites (within our lan ip doesn't work), but it can be accessed outside with the static ip?

My traceroute result is as follows:

```
tracert xxx.xxx.16.247

Tracing route to localhost [xxx.xxx.16.247]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  2     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  3    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  localhost [xxx.xxx.16.247]
```

My problem is I was able to access my website with locally configured ip address of the machine (e.g 192.168.0.1) but can't be accessed through static ip which was configured for the server (e.g xxx.xxx.16.247), I cross checked firewalls and ports all are configured proper. How to resolve this?

Comment: Hairpin NAT ?   <!-- comment must be at least 15 chars in length -->

Answer (score 1):

as far as I understood you tried to access your webserver in lan by the same ip as you do from wan. If though what does traceroute say?
How is your port fowarding configured?

Edit:
Regarding to your traceroute I suppose your port fowarding configuration is incomplete.
Your router knows its ip-adresses (including the one you wanted to access), so you are directly sending your query to your router (which I assume is also your default gateway).
Problem here is the most common operating system on routers assume you only want to foward ports from your "internet interface" (most common pppoe) to your lan bridge. As result of that there will be no option in the web interface to configure port fowarding from the lan bridge. Without Portfowarding in your lan interface your router will drop all packets directed to this ip.
Maybe you can configure your router via cli, e.g. ssh or telnet.
What router are you using?

Edit2:
There are some options now to fix this:

1.) Use the local Ip-Adress to access your webserver
2.) Try to solve the problem descriped in my frist Edit.
3.) Get a router/os that supports local portfowarding(destination nat)

If you got enough time i would suggest 2.) followed by these steps:
1. Enable ssh or telnet in your router
2. Download putty or activate telnet in windows (i assume you are using a windows machine)
3. Connect via ssh or telnet to your router.
4. Search the cli manual of your router for a option to setup portfoward(maybe called destination nat)

Found this right here in forum [Thread](https://superuser.com/questions/37421/accessing-a-website-via-the-webservers-public-ip-from-a-pc-within-the-same-lan?rq=1) i think this is the same problem you got. Maybe the solution to unix based router operating system there does work for your router.

Comment: tracert timed out :(,updated with traceroute info kindly have a look on it

Comment: timed out at first hop? then i assume the problem lies within port fowarding, be sure to also foward http/-s ports from lan.

Comment: we are using netgear router mate

Comment: there is no way i can help you just by knowing the producers name. And unfortunately i am not into netgear cli commands. what u need to search if you want to try it with your router (there is no guarantee that it can be done with cli) is sth. like this: [manual](http://www.downloads.netgear.com/docs/m4100/enu/202-11161-01/cli.pdf). of course u need to search the manual for your router type.